# Manual time syncing

Tags: command-line, kde, plasma, date

Is there a command or some option in KDE environment with which I can manually sync system's time and date with a time server (eg Public Time Server (pool.ntp.org))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should be able to use `ntpdate`

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

You might also choose to use `ntpd` (which would then be automated, not manual) -

```
sudo apt-get install ntpd
```

Edit "/etc/ntp.conf", and add (for example) -

```
server 0.pool.ntp.org
server 1.pool.ntp.org
server 2.pool.ntp.org
```

Comment: any way to bypass `sudo` for `ntpdate`?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Changing the system time requires super user permissions. You could add it to a startup script (automation), or use ntpd (automation) or perhaps write a script to sudo for you.